# Gettings errors with Textmate using Git bundle

Tags: git, textmate, bundle, textmatebundles

Trying to use Textmate with the Git bundle. Running into errors when trying any option.

```
/Users/colby/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/Git.tmbundle/Support/tmvc/../lib/git.rb:131:in `paths': No selected files. (RuntimeError) from /Users/colby/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/Git.tmbundle/Support/tmvc/../lib/git.rb:80:in `path' from /Users/colby/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/Git.tmbundle/Support/tmvc/../lib/git.rb:199:in `merge_message' from /Users/colby/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/Git.tmbundle/Support/tmvc/../app/controllers/commit_controller.rb:6:in `index' from /Users/colby/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/Git.tmbundle/Support/tmvc/lib/application_controller.rb:105:in `send' from /Users/colby/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/Git.tmbundle/Support/tmvc/lib/application_controller.rb:105:in `call' from /Users/colby/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/Git.tmbundle/Support/tmvc/lib/application_controller.rb:94:in `with_filters' from /Users/colby/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/Git.tmbundle/Support/tmvc/lib/application_controller.rb:105:in `call' from /Users/colby/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/Git.tmbundle/Support/tmvc/lib/application_controller.rb:112:in `call' from /Users/colby/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/Git.tmbundle/Support/tmvc/tmvc.rb:56:in `dispatch_normal' from /Users/colby/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/Git.tmbundle/Support/tmvc/tmvc.rb:74:in `dispatch' from /Users/colby/Library/Application Support/TextMate/Bundles/Git.tmbundle/Support/tmvc/tmvc.rb:96:in `dispatch' from /tmp/temp_textmate.hNAQFu:4
```

My `TM_GIT` is set to the same dir as `which git`. Really lost and looking for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the exact same error. For me updating the git bundle in the Terminal solved the problem:

```
$ cd ~/Library/Application\ Support/TextMate/Bundles/Git.tmbundle/
$ git pull
```

After a TextMate restart the problem should be gone.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [source code of git.rb](http://gitorious.com/git-tmbundle/mainline/blobs/master/Support/lib/git.rb), you will see it looks for the following environment variables for determining paths:

- '`TM_SELECTED_FILES`'
- '`TM_PROJECT_DIRECTORY`'
- '`TM_FILEPATH`'
- '`TM_DIRECTORY`'

So to start debug this, you could look as to why those variables are not set.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can only run Git bundle commands while opening a file in a Git managed folder.
Try opening a file in a Git repository and the "Git Update" will start working.